# What's the best way to apply barrel distortion to a SCNView?

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, metal

I have a scene with a left and right `SCNView` that, when shown in Google Cardboard, gives a nice stereoscopic view. I'd like to add barrel distortion to my two views to correct for the different lenses in Cardboard.

Does anyone have some good suggestions on how I can do this using SCNView / Metal / SceneKit? I'd prefer not to drop down into OpenGL and mess with the renderer.

My thought is applying a transform to the `SCNView` might work well.

Thanks in Advance,

J.

Comment: @rickster That's one old way to do it using OpenGL. Like I ask in my question, I would like to see a solution SCNView / Metal. Its not a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The `MDLCamera` class has a `barrelDistortion` property. I don't know if that would work for you though; you might need an inverse barrel distortion? `MDLCamera` is bridged to `SCNCamera`, but you must `import SceneKit.ModelIO` (as noted in your [OBJ import answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667969/how-do-you-convert-wavefront-obj-file-to-an-scnnode-with-model-i-o).

Sounds like a cool blog post once it's working!

Comment: Model I/O was designed as a format that you can use to import and export assets. While SceneKit offers utils to load assets represented as Model I/O objects, it's not true that everything Model I/O can represent is supported by SceneKit. Many properties of `MDLCamera` are not supported by SceneKit, and `barrelDistortion` is one of them.

Comment: What happens if I create an MDLCamera that has properties that don't exist in SceneKit? Do I get a best effort translation, or a completely stock SCNCamera, or are the results undefined? Do the SCNCamera focal parameters reflect the MDLCamera aperture/lens/etc. ?

Comment: Model I/O is, in some sense, an interchange format specification. It *describes* aspects of scene graphs and assets, but doesn't do anything more than describe. It's up to higher-level tools to read the description and do whatever they can with it. In the case of SceneKit, one can safely assume that if you import a MDL object of some sort as the corresponding SCN class, only features that said SCN class has API for will be imported.