# Objective-C Scenekit: Import OBJ-File externally and color it

Tags: object, colors, scenekit

I am new to this. And there comes my first problem.

I build an object loader with SceneKit. I got the path, the Object is available, but I have no clue how I can color the shown object.

```
ScnScene *testScene = [SCNScene sceneWithURL:url options:nil error:NULL];
testScene.background.contents = [UIImage imageWithName:@"color.png"];

[self.mainView.scene.rootnode addChildNode:testScene.rootNode];
```

This didn't work. I also  tried with:

```
SCNMaterialProperty *testColor = [SCNMaterialProperty materialPropertyWithContents [UIImage imageNamed:@"color.png"]];
testScene.rootnode.geometry.materials = testcolor;
```

Or:

```
SCNMaterial *testColor = [SCNMaterial material];
testColor.diffuse.contesnts = [UIColor redColor];
testScene.rootnode.geometry.firstMaterial = testColor;
```

Nothing works. When I start the app, every object is displayed. So far the OBJ-Loader works out very well. But everything is still gray. I totally have no clue how to color the displayed objects. Has anyone a hint/idea/solution for me?

Btw. I want to avoid that I have to build a geometry out of the OBJ-Informations manually. So I try to solve this by the SCNScene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major problem was that the import by a `SCNScene`does not work that way. So the right solution is to import the obj.file into a `SCNNode`, add a `SCNMaterial` with the chosen color (or an image) to the `SCNNode` and give the `SCNNode`to the `SCNScene`. To load the obj.file, you need to import that by Model IO Framework.

I will give some code how I made it colorful.

```
#import <SceneKit/SceneKit.h>
#import <ModelIO/ModelIO.h>
#import <SceneKit/ModelIO.h>
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic) SCNView* mainView;
```

....

```
MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url];     
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene scene];
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode nodeWithMDLObject:[asset objectAtIndex:0]];

SCNMaterial *material = [SCNMaterial material];
material.diffuse.contents = [UIColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0.1 brightness:0.5 alpha:1];
node.geometry.firstMaterial = material;

[scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
[self.mainView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:scene.rootNode];
```

Alternately you can add a color by this:

`material.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"farbe.png"];`

Now you can import any obj.file externally (from any chosen folder you like) and color it.

Thanks to SGlindemann, cashmash and Hal Mueller, who helped out to find that solution.

---

UPDATE (29.1.2017)

Somehow the way above does not work anymore. I did not figure out yet what changed. But I made another code that makes loading for 3D files possible (from `mainBundle`, not externally). Here I start from a `SCNNode` class which is called by the `ViewController.m`. The `SCNScene` is setup in the `ViewController`. Following there is the code which I wrote for the `SCNNode` class.

Before you start, put the .obj and .mtl file (both with same name) into your Xcode project. You don't need to convert it to a scene.

```
#import <ModelIO/ModelIO.h>
#import <SceneKit/ModelIO.h>
```

...

```
@property (nonatomic) SCNNode *objectNode;
```

...

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
            pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name of the obj.file"]
            ofType:@"obj"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url];

// Create the Block
self.objectNode = [SCNNode nodeWithMDLObject:[asset objectAtIndex:0]];


[self addChildNode: self.objectNode];

return self;
```

This returned `self` has to be added into your view.

```
[self.view.scene.rootNode addChildNode:returnedObj];
```

The `MDLAsset`loads the .obj-file with the corresponding .mtl-file and png-File. I used this code to load objects from MagicaVoxel (this exports obj+mtl+png at once). I did not get deep into it yet.

I did NOT try this code with external loadings or typing in colors manually via `SCNMaterial`. So there is no statement whether this works or not. I did not try.

Comment: Hey, i tried this code but i am getting white screen only. No 3d model. Can you help?

Comment: Hey, I got the problem too. Somehow they changed something so that the external loading does not work anymore. I made another code which is working (loading via mainbundle + using .obj and .mtl file).

I update the post above with my new code. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example will set the background of the scene but do nothing with your object.

Your second example should be giving you some compiler warnings. You're assigning a single `SCNMaterialProperty` to `testScene.rootnode.geometry.materials`, which expects an array of `SCNMaterial` (not `SCNMaterialProperty`). Is that your real code?

The final example shouldn't compile at all: you've misspelled `contents` as `contesnts`. Other than that, it ought to work.

Note that `MDLAsset` can import an OBJ file and return an `SCNNode`. See [How do you convert Wavefront OBJ file to an SCNNode with Model I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667969/how-do-you-convert-wavefront-obj-file-to-an-scnnode-with-model-i-o). If the object is an asset you'll be shipping with your project, save it as an `SCNScene` (which is compact and optimized), and ship that, not the original OBJ.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I rewrote the code manually, because my laptop with the code was used by another person at that moment. There came the wrong code spelling from. Sorry for that.

I used the `MDLAsset` as you suggested. Overall it doesn't work to add a color by `SCNMaterial` to a `SCNScene`, but it works if I import the obj.file to a `SCNNode`. So everything I tried on the first run were wrong.

I will add the solution I found to make everything a bit more colorful.

But really thank you very much. Without your `MDLAsset` insertion this problem would have driven me crazy.